# Counter code loading small image

Tags: javascript, counter

I've found a website statistics counter that runs this code:

```
<a title='counter' target='_blank' href='http://www.example.com/tracker/'>
  <img src='http://www.example.com/transparent.gif' border='0'>
</a>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/tracker/example.js.php?id=11111'>
</script>
<noscript>
  <a href='http://www.example.com/'>Counter</a>
</noscript>
```

I think the main part is just for SEO, right? Would the counter still work the same way by using just this part of it?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/tracker/example.js.php?id=111111">
</script>
```

I'm always wondering why free services loading a small image and such things.
Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Well, I think the best way is to try it and see what happens ;)

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it seems to be still working. But some more in depth things are hard to analyze...

Answer (score 0):

The image might be part of the tracking and I assume it is a fallback for people with javascript disabled.
In this case the tracking service can still track the incoming request from your IP/Browser for this image (which is blank and not interferring with your design).